# trying to print _G doesn't work

Tags: lua

According to the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html) _G "holds the global environment". I wanted to see what's inside it so I wrote the following code to print _G but it doesn't work:

```
function f(x)
    return 2*x
end
a=3
b="hello world"
print("_G has "..#_G.." elements")
for k,v in pairs(_G) do
    print(k)
    print(_G[k])
    print("G["..k.."]=".._G[k])
end
```

Error:

```
_G has 0 elements
a
3
G[a]=3
string
table: 003C8448
lua: try_G.lua:10: attempt to concatenate field '?' (a table value)
stack traceback:
    try_G.lua:10: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
>Exit code: 1
```

Comment: See also http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo?globals

Comment: You know, it's traditional to mark the answer of the guy who came up with the solution as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works exactly as expected- it loops through _G and attempts to print the contents. Unfortunately, _G contains many tables which cannot be concatenated into a string. The code fails because _G["_G"] = _G. That means that when the interpreter comes to

```
print("G["..k.."]=".._G[k])
```

then k is "_G" and _G[k] is _G, and you attempt to concatenate a table- which the interpreter can't do, so it dies on you. There are numerous other tables in _G which would also cause this failure.

Comment: it doesn't have to be the "_G" key: could be any of the standard libraries (string,table,etc); or even some global he's made himself.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the `table.foreach(t,f)` function. It iterates over a table `t`, calling the function `f` with each key and value pair. Use with `print` to get a quick view:

```
table.foreach(_G,print)
```

This is really handy at the interactive prompt as it is reasonably succinct and easy enough to type.

```
C:\Users\Ross>lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> table.foreach(_G,print)
string  table: 005CE3D0
xpcall  function: 00717E80
package table: 005CE088
tostring        function: 00717DE0
print   function: 00711CB8
os      table: 005CE358
unpack  function: 00717E40
require function: 00718360
getfenv function: 00711B58
setmetatable    function: 00717DA0
next    function: 00711C38
assert  function: 00711A38
tonumber        function: 00717DC0
io      table: 005CE218
rawequal        function: 00711CF8
collectgarbage  function: 00711A78
getmetatable    function: 00711B98
module  function: 00718320
rawset  function: 00711D58
math    table: 005CE448
debug   table: 005CE498
pcall   function: 00711C78
table   table: 005CE128
newproxy        function: 00711E10
type    function: 00717E00
coroutine       table: 005CDFE8
_G      table: 00713EC8
select  function: 00711D98
gcinfo  function: 00711B18
pairs   function: 00711F98
rawget  function: 00711D18
loadstring      function: 00711C18
ipairs  function: 00711F68
_VERSION        Lua 5.1
dofile  function: 00711A98
setfenv function: 00717D60
load    function: 00711BD8
error   function: 00711AD8
loadfile        function: 00711BB8
>
```

**Update:** Unfortunately, as Alexander Gladysh reminds me, the `table.foreach` function was deprecated in Lua 5.1, and a quick check of the current beta release of 5.2 shows that it has been removed in Lua 5.2. It is easy to write the same loop in terms of `pairs`:

```
for k,v in pairs(_G) do print(k,v) end
```

which should give the same output as `table.foreach(_G,print)` would. The key feature that I'm leaning on here is that `print` is defined to call `tostring()` on each argument you pass, and `tostring()` is defined to return some sort of sensible string for every kind of value, even those like functions that don't have a good representation as a string. The details will differ on each platform, but the default implementation of `tostring()` includes the address of the table or function in its string result, allowing you to at least recognize that _G.os and _G.io are *distinct* tables.

For more human-friendly table printing, there are a lot of solutions, ranging from examples in [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/12.1.html) to several persistent data libraries. Personally, I like the [`pl.pretty.write()`](http://stevedonovan.github.com/Penlight/api/modules/pl.pretty.html#write) function provided by [steve donavan's penlight](http://stevedonovan.github.com/Penlight/api/index.html) library.

Comment: Note that `table.foreach()` is deprecated in 5.1

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that. Its a shame, because it is handy for this kind of quick inspection at the interactive prompt.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on DeadMG, change your

```
print("G["..k.."]=".._G[k])
```

to

```
print("G["..k.."]=",_G[k])
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: You could also print `v` instead of `_G[k]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final code using DeadMG's solution:

```
function f(x)
    return 2*x
end
a=3
b="hello world"
print("_G has "..#_G.." elements")
for k,v in pairs(_G) do
    if k~="_G" then
        if type(v)=="string" or type(v)=="number" then
            print("G["..k.."]="..v)
        else
            print("G["..k.."]=("..type(v)..")")
        end
    end
end
```